# A series of sub-Gaussian variable with uniform bound on the second moment

Tags: probability, statistics

For a series of mean-zero sub-Gaussian random variables $X_1,\dots,X_n,\dots$, we known there   is a constant M such that $EX_i^2 \le M, \forall i$. I was wondering that can we establish a uniform bound on their sub-Gaussian norm? Thank you.